# Find the general solution of the ODE $xy′′ − y′ + 4x^3y = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone help me figure out this ODE, its driving me crazy. I dont need a full solution beacuse that would take hours but maybe just the final answer?

Find the general solution of the ODE
$xy′′ − y′ + 4x^3y = 0$
assuming $x > 0$ and given that $y_1(x) = \sin(x^2)$ is a solution.

Comment: It's $C_1 \sin(x^2)+C_2 \cos(x^2)$, see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+y%27%27+-+y%27+%2B+4+x%5E3+y%3D0)

Comment: You already have one solution, so assume the second solution is of the form $y_2(x)=u_1(x)\cdot y_1(x)$. Plug it in the equation and solve it. This method called order reduction - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order. Good luck!

Comment: It's obvious that $\sin^2(x)$ is *not* a solution of this ODE

Comment: Quote: "I dont need a full solution beacuse that would take hours but maybe just the final answer?"

Answer (score 2):

You can express the second (unknown) solution $y_2$ to this ODE in terms of the first (known) solution $y_1$ and the Wronskian $w$.

First, the Wronskian. By definition, we have
\begin{equation}
 w = y_1 y_2' - y_1' y_2. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Taking the derivative on both sides, we obtain
\begin{equation}
 w' = y_1' y_2' + y_1 y_2'' - y_1' y_2' - y_1'' y_2 = y_1 y_2'' - y_1'' y_2.
 \tag{2}
\end{equation}
We know that both $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions to the original ODE, so we can write
\begin{align}
 x y_1'' &= y_1' - 4 x^3 y_1, \\
 x y_2'' &= y_2' - 4 x^3 y_2.
\end{align}
Combining this with $(2)$, we get
\begin{equation}
 x w' = y_1(y_2' -4 x^3 y_2) - y_2(y_1' - 4 x^3 y_1) = y_1 y_2' - y_1' y_2 = w,
\end{equation}
so the Wronskian $w$ obeys the ODE
\begin{equation}
w' = \frac{1}{x} w. \tag{3}
\end{equation}
It is not difficult to solve $(3)$ for $w$.

Second, the unknown solution $y_2$. We look again at equation $(1)$, and realise that we know *two* of the three ingredients, namely $w$ and $y_1$. That means that we can re-order $(1)$ to obtain an ODE for $y_2$:
\begin{equation}
 y_2' = \frac{y_1'}{y_1}\,y_2 + \frac{w}{y_1} \tag{4}
\end{equation}
This is a linear, first order ODE for $y_2$. Using the explicit expressions for $w$ and $y_1$, you can solve now $(4)$ for $y_2$.

**Note:** This approach works for every second order equation where you are given one of the two solutions; it does not depend on finding a 'clever' variable substitution.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$xy''(x)-y'(x)+4x^3y(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $t=x^2$, which gives $x=\sqrt{t}$:

---

$$y''(x)\sqrt{t}-y'(x)+4t^{\frac{3}{2}}y(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Using the chain rule:

---

$$-2\sqrt{t}y'(t)+\sqrt{t}\left(4ty''(t)+2y'(t)\right)+4t^{\frac{3}{2}}y(t)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$4t^{\frac{3}{2}}\left(y''(t)+y(t)\right)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y''(t)+y(t)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Assume a solution will be proportional to $e^{\lambda t}$ for some constant $\lambda$.

Substitute $y(t)=e^{\lambda t}$ into the differential equation:

---

$$\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\left(e^{\lambda t}\right)+e^{\lambda t}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute $\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\left(e^{\lambda t}\right)=\lambda^2e^{\lambda t}$:

---

$$\lambda^2e^{\lambda t}+e^{\lambda t}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{\lambda t}\left(\lambda^2+1\right)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Since $e^{\lambda t}\ne0$ for any finite $\lambda$, the zeros must come from the polynomial:

---

$$\lambda^2+1=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\lambda=\pm i$$

Comment: You should use another name for the changed function, $u(t)=y(x)=y(\sqrt t)$ resp. $y(x)=u(x^2)$, since these functions are different.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The second solution is $y_2(x)=v(x)·y_1(x)$ where 
$$
v(x)=\int \frac{e^{-\int P(x)dx}}{y_1(x)^2}\;dx
$$ where $P(x)=\frac{-1}{x}$ in your case.